# Snowflake not recognising my values are timestamps. I need them as timestamps (can't upload as varchar)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here's a sample from my column, they're all in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "upload"? Have you tried using the to_timestamp function to convert from varchar to timestamp?

Comment: Via the GUI. Yes tried it didn't work. Via a query you mean?

Comment: Can you stage it to a temporary table without data manipulation, and then use the SQL query to convert to timestamp for your permanent table?

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to timestamp before you upload.

```
    create table temp1 (
      id integer, 
      time varchar(30)
    );

    insert into temp1 values 
      (1, '11/09/2019 11:28'), 
      (2, '13/11/2019 15:53');
```

Occasionally people may try using MM for minutes, but it's actually MI. That's fixed some errors on some of the posts found on this site.

```
    select id, time, 
      to_timestamp(time, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MI')
    from temp1

    OUTPUT:
    1   11/09/2019 11:28    2019-09-11 11:28:00.000
    2   13/11/2019 15:53    2019-11-13 15:53:00.000
```

Comment: As noted in this answer, you are using the incorrect timestamp format.  It is not `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` but rather `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi`.  You can specify that format in your file format so that when you upload your data, it will correctly load it directly as timestamp.